# How to create a python module where user can call feature (String.substringing) to get corresponding values to be used in function

Tags: python, pandas, class

**My Goal**

My Example table

```
 Equipment  Sub-Eq  

Blenders    Kneader 5.0141  0.5867  0.3224  0.14 3
            Ribbon  4.1366  0.5072  0.007   0.7 11
            Rotary  4.1366  0.5072  0.007   0.7 11
```

Containing Equipment name(String) and sub-equipment name (sub_string) & corresponding data (Numarical)

Now I want to create a module, so that after importing the module.

```
`import Equipment_Data `
```

user can call String.Sub_string(Index) (Example from Picture: Blender.Kneder (K1)) would return the value 5.0141 (From Picture)

My current code is very inefficient

```
Blenders_Kneader=np.array([5.0141,0.5867,0.3224,0.14,3 ]) # Volume mcube
Blenders_Ribbon=np.array([4.1366,0.5072,0.007,0.7,11 ]) # Volume mcube
Blenders_Rotary=np.array([4.1366,0.5072,0.007,0.7,11 ]) # Volume mcube
```

**My questions**

Should I use class for one equipment and objects as sub-equipment? And values as Numpy array

or Should I use Pandas Dataframe?

or Should I use Numpy Array?

Appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Thank you I have edited the post.